# How to create a custom Mii fighter character for Smash Bros Ultimate?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I want to create a custom Mii fighter character for my boyfriends birthday coming up. I've done some research and it seems there are a couple ways to do this - however I am looking to get advice because ideally I would like this to be a surprise, but most articles seem to indicate that I need to build this using his Nintendo Switch console, or in his account. I have a few questions about this actually, and I know most of these groups like each question to be posted in its own thread, so I apologize, and will try to group them by specific topic.

1. **I heard that in order to even use the Mii fighter characters, you need to unlock them through something called "story-mode"?** I know that he only plays against other people, either online match-ups or with his roommate in person. Would this prevent me from being able to create a character for him to use and access?
2. I want to create a Mii character that looks like him, and heard that you can create one from a photo? I found something called "Mii Maker" that says you can do this by taking a picture with the Wii U GamePad camera - however no one I know owns a Wii..... **is there another way to make a Mii fighter character from a photo without using the Wii console?**
3. I would like this to be a surprise - so if I am able to create a character - **is it possible to create it in another console, or in another account, and then transfer it to him somehow,** on his birthday? QR code? Send as a gift?

and FINALLY

4. There seem to be numerous varying opinions on which Mii fighter is best: Gunner, Swordfighter, or Brawler. My bf mains Bayonetta, and will sometimes use Dark Pit or Dr. Mario as alternatives - **so which do you think would be the best choice for someone who uses these characters?**

Comment: Hi Kaleigh, welcome to Arqade! We are a question and answer site rather than a forum - as such we usually try and stick to one question per post, maaybe two, if the second one is closely related to the first. You're probably best splitting some of your numbered points out into their own separate questions. You can always link back to this question if it helps to provide the context :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(click for larger images)

## Creating a Mii Fighter in Smash Ultimate

#### 1.  Build yourself a Mii

- Navigate to System Settings

  [image: System Settings]
- Go down to 'Mii' and select 'Create/Edit a Mii'

  [image: Mii]
- I'd suggest using 'Choose a Look-Alike'

  [image: Mii Creation]
- Press 'Y' to shuffle the random faces until you find a good template

  [image: Mii Look-Alike]
- Tweak him until he looks just right, give him a name and you're good to go!

#### 2. Build yourself a Mii Fighter

- Pop open the game (in your boyfriend's account) and navigate to Games & More

  [image: Games & More selection]
- Select "Mii Fighter"

  [image: Mii Fighter selection]
- Choose a fighter type, moveset, etc. and then customize to your heart's content!

  [image: Mii Fighter creation]

---

## Some answers to your questions...

> I heard that in order to even use the Mii fighter characters, you need to unlock them through something called "story-mode"?

Unlocking the different Mii Fighters through World of Light (WoL), is *one* way to have fighters be created for you (and the only way to earn the "default" Mii Fighters). But WoL is not needed to create Mii Fighters. You can follow the above steps without ever playing WoL.

> I want to create a Mii character that looks like him, and heard that you can create one from a photo? I found something called "Mii Maker" that says you can do this by taking a picture with the Wii U GamePad camera - however no one I know owns a Wii..... is there another way to make a Mii fighter character from a photo without using the Wii console?

Minor distinction, but the Wii and Wii U were actually two separate consoles. So you wouldn't be looking for someone with a Wii, but the even more obscure Wii U! (this is assuming there's a way to even transfer Mii's over, which I haven't looked into)

Instead of going that route, I'd use the "Choose a Look-Alike" option I detailed above. Keep shuffling until you find a generated Mii that looks close enough, and then go in to tweak whatever needs fixing.

> I would like this to be a surprise - so if I am able to create a character - is it possible to create it in another console, or in another account, and then transfer it to him somehow, on his birthday? QR code? Send as a gift?

I've [read](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/aon76y/easiest_way_to_transfer_mii_fighters/) that this can be done using Amiibo--you would create the Mii Fighter on one Switch, save it to the Amiibo, and then use that to transfer it to another. But I haven't tested it, so I can't guarantee it's possible.

The biggest problem you'll run into with this secrecy is that Mii Fighters only show on the character selection screen if you've created one of that type. So, for example, if you create a Mii Swordfighter when before he had no Mii Fighters on his system, the selection screen may look like this:

[image: CSS with Mii Swordsman]

Notice how there's just a Mii Swordfighter there at the end. If he's used to seeing the selection screen without, then this may be a dead giveaway. So be careful!

> There seem to be numerous varying opinions on which Mii fighter is best: Gunner, Swordfighter, or Brawler. My bf mains Bayonetta, and will sometimes use Dark Pit or Dr. Mario as alternatives - so which do you think would be the best choice for someone who uses these characters?

If he mains Bayonetta, Dark Pit and Dr. Mario, it sounds like your boyfriend is a brawler. All of those characters want to be up close and personal so they can combo the crap out of you. They all only have one real projectile, and that's only used to let them get close, so Gunner's out. None of them have swords or disjoints for carefully spacing approaches/attacks, so Swordfighter's out.

Therefore, I'd suggest Mii Brawler as the best fit for your boyfriend from what you've told us. Brawler (like the name implies), does best when he's right up in your face. Some of his movesets also include a single projectile to help him get close, just like your boyfriend's characters.

Good luck!!

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I see that my entire question was closed so I hope you still get this message - thank you so much @scohe001 - this was a perfect answer, you even made a great recommendation to go with the Brawler - I wouldn't have figured that out on my own. Unfortunately, I never got around to doing any of this because he broke up with me in what was the single most strangest and confusing way possible. F-ck this pandemic, it has taken so many things from me - I miss the days when I used to be able to play video games, and nothing was sad.